# Как ограничить кол-во прохождений теста?

Tags: php, html, сессия

Человек проходит регистрацию на сайте и эти данные сохраняются в `$_SESSION`, потом он проходит тест(на другой странице), отправляет эти данные(POST методом) и они сохраняются на сервере вместе со значениями `$_SESSION` введенными при регистрации. Но я заметил что некоторые проходят тест далеко не один раз и засоряют файл с результатами(под одним `$_SESSION`, только возвращаются на страницу к тесту). Как сделать фильтр, чтобы он сохранял от одного пользователя результаты например не более 5 раз? Я так понимаю это надо делать с помощью  `$_SESSION`, ставить фильтр именно по нему, но у меня пока нет идей именно как.

Comment: Запишите в сесии что-то уникальное, к примеру рандомное число (не совсем уникальное значение, но чем больше тем меньше вероятность совпадения) . И создайте еще значение в сесии, при сохранении добавляйте в него +1. Ну и теперь просто условие. Думаю понятно. Как вариант, не самый лучший конечно, но может натолкнет вас на мысль. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Ввести в таблицу результатов теста поле Попытка(ENUM:1,2,3,4,5 NOT NULL) и создать уникальный индекс (Сессия, Попытка). Всё... хоть на пупе извернись, а больше 5 результатов для одной сессии в таблицу сервер не примет.